# Is the intersection of a core-free maximal subgroup with an abelian normal subgroup, trivial?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H<G$ a core-free maximal subgroup and $A \triangleleft G$ an  abelian normal subgroup.

> **Question**: Is it true that $A \cap H = \{e\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, here is a *proof*:

First of all $A \cap H \triangleleft H$, and $A \cap H \triangleleft A$ because $A$ abelian.  So $A \cap H \triangleleft \langle H, A \rangle$.
Now by maximality $\langle H, A \rangle \in \{ H,G \}$:
If  $\langle H, A \rangle = H$ then $A < H$ and so $A=\{e\} = A \cap H  $, by core-free assumption.
Else $A \cap H \triangleleft G $ and so $A \cap H=\{e\}$ (also by core-free assumption). $\square$